# Create multiple background using SASS mixin

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to create a mixin in Sass to generate multiple background, problem is the number of background is unknow, it's can be 3, 4 or even 5. Here what I try and fail.

```
@mixin multiBg($page: index, $sec: sec01,$from: 1, $to: 3, $type: jpg){
    $url: (); // i'm try to create a empty array first
    $newUrl: null; // and an empty variable
    @for $i from $from through $to {
        $newUrl: append($url, url(../img/#{$page}/#{$sec}_bg0#{$i}.#{$type})); // then append value to variable;
    }
    background: $newUrl;
}

#sec05 {
   @include multiBg(index,sec05);
}
```

**current output:**

```
background: url(../img/index/sec05_bg03.jpg);
```

**expected output:**

```
background: url(../img/sec05_bg01.jpg),url(../img/sec05_bg02.jpg), url(../img/sec05_bg03.jpg);
```

I don't know how to fix this problem since i'm still learing SASS. Can someone enlighten me please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track! But your syntax and logic are slightly off. Here's what I came up with:

```
@mixin multiBg($page: index, $sec: sec01, $from: 1, $to: 5, $type: jpg) {

  $url_list: ();

  @for $i from $from through $to {

    // I broke constructing the url and adding it to the set into two steps here.
    // We could do this all at once, but separating it can make it easier to read.

    // First, generate the url. 
    $url_string: url(../img/#{$page}/#{$sec}_bg0#{$i}.#{$type});

    // Then add it to the list (the 'comma' part is important)
    $url_list: append($url_list, $url_string, comma);  
  }

  // Done looping? Output the final list!
  background-image: $url_list;
}
```

That seems to return what you're looking for. Here are the [official docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#list-functions) on list functions - I always forget one or two, may be useful for you too.

Also, since you mentioned you're new to sass - check out [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com) if you haven't already. It's a handy little sandbox for quickly prototyping and trying things out in sass; similar to [Codepen](http://codepen.io) but a bit more specialized. It's what I used to experiment with this question.

Comment: oh wow, thank for your answer, it's just perfect!!. And also thank for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a cleaner answer, I believe.

```
@mixin image-resolve($image) {
  $images: ();

   @each $i in $image {
     $path: ();

     $images: append($images, $path, comma);
   }

 background-image: $images;
}
```